# Compact long string with PathEllipsis in .Net

Tags: .net, drawstring, string-conversion, textrenderer

I have following string, which i am drawing in one of my treeview control using DrawString.

```
@haTEST sadasd asd asd asd asd asd asd asd ### adssad asd asd asd asd asd asdasdasd
```

The treeview is drawing the above string like following:

[image]

Now,i want to compact the same string shown in above image to another string.
I have tried http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/NewPathCompactPath.aspx

but, it didn't provide me the above image result.

Please let me know, how to get the same result using `TextRenderer.MeasureText` for same string.

Thanks